# Binary and Bits

Tags: binary

Here's a question I've come across:

Assume each X represents one bit, either 0 or 1. Consider the 8-bit unsigned binary numbers A = 1XXX XXXX and B = 0XXX XXXX. Which of the following are true (you may tick more than one answer):
A    B > A
B    A > 127
C    Can't tell which one A or B is larger
D    B < 127
E    A > B

Explanations needed (0 understanding on this). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key to the answer is in the word unsigned. This means that the MSB (left most bit) is not being used to indicate the results sign. Processors perform mathematical operations such as add, subtract and comparison on numbers using twos compliment,  this means that to know what the numeric value of a binary word is we must know if it is signed (can contain negative values) or unsigned (positive numbers only).

So in the above case the values are unsigned, which means A is always greater than B and that A has the MSB of an 8 bit value set to 1 so must be at least 128.
In the same way that we count in units of 10s binary works in units of two:
Binary
128  64  32  16  8  4  2  1
Decimal
1000  100  10  1

However if the binary value were signed the left most bit would be used to express positve (0) or negative (1) and when negative we need to invert the value and add one to get back to the (Negative) result.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Why is it that when the msb is set to 1 it's at least 128?

Comment: Binary numbering works just like decimal but with powers of two instead of ten. So the weightings start at 1 then 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and lastly 128. So in A where the leftmost (or most significant) bit is 1, this implies 1 * 128. Just like 100 in decmal implies 1 * 100.